# Hide div when clicked outside or hover across border

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following example, if you click the link, it displays the `div` element.

How can I hide the `div` when you click beyond the boundaries of the block or mouse across the border?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a').click(function () {
    $('.bg').css({'display': 'block'});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">Click</a>
<div style="background: #222; display:none" class="bg">Trololo</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the element once you've clicked anywhere in the document other than the link or the div, you have to monitor the click event for the document, then compare the clicked element against the link and the div, then check if the div is visible. If those conditions are all met then show the div.

To hide the element once you've "moused out" of the div, use [`jQuery.mouseout()`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var bg = $('.bg'), a = $('a');
  a.click(function(){
    bg.toggle();
  });
  $(document).click(function(e){
    if(!a.is(e.target) && !bg.is(e.target) && bg.is(':visible')) {
      bg.hide();
    }
  })
  bg.mouseout(function(){
    bg.hide();
  })
});
```

```css
.bg {
  background: #222;                                                               color: #fff; line-height: 50px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">Click</a>
<div class="bg" style="display:none">Trololo</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/k0r5bh0t/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a').click(function () {
            $('.bg').css({
                'display': 'block'
            });
        });
        $(document).click(function(e){
          if(e.target.id !='myBg' && e.target.id !='clickme'){
                $('.bg').hide();
          }
        })
    });
```

I have added ID to click me button and div which needs to be hidden.
This should work

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <div class="col-sm-12"> <a href="#" id="clickme">Click</a>

        <div style="background: #222" class="bg" id="myBg">Trololo</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        $('.bg').show();
    });
    $('.bg').mouseout(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

This hides ".bg" when the mouse moves out of the black box. No clicking required.